# Is it possible to publish multiple messages at once using the RabbitMQ client for C#?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Right now, our publishing code for large amounts of messages looks like so:

```
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    publisher.Publish(message);
}
```

Does there exist the ability to send more than one message over the channel at once?

```
publisher.Publish(messages);
```

or as so if we chunk

```
var chunks = messages.Chunk(100);
foreach (var chunk in chunks)
{
    publisher.Publish(chunk);
}
```

Comment: I've looked around, and I don't think RabbitMQ supports batching. Do you have really high latency between your server and client?

Comment: @Asad yes, that is exactly the case. We don't publish often, but when we do we have around 500k messages to publish.

Comment: Have you actually profiled and identified this as being a bottleneck in your system? I think the best thing here would just be to publish like you're doing now and let AMQP take care of it as fast as your network and consumers will allow. If you really are having performance problems, perhaps it is possible to send a custom "chunked" message, as you're doing above, then have something closer to the consumers receive it and publish the constituent messages.

Comment: @Asad It is not a bottleneck, but it is causing a timeout. In that I mean the call into the service performing the publishes times out. Maybe we need to re-visit how we are wrapping our publish code, as we currently have a singleton publisher w/ an internal lock (as channels are not thread-safe). Sending an aggregate of messages would work too.

Comment: MultiThreading publish using more channels ? why not?

Answer (score 10):

With current version of RabbitMq(3.8.2) you can send batch messages as below for c# client sdk:

```cs
basicPublishBatch = channel.CreateBasicPublishBatch();
basicPublishBatch.Add("exchange", "routeKey", false, null, new byte[]{1});
basicPublishBatch.Add("exchange", "routeKey", false, null, new byte[]{1});
basicPublishBatch.Publish();
```

Check this PR:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/pull/368

Answer (score 3):

For RabbitMQ the AMQP protocol is asynchronous for produce and consume operations so it is not clear how to benefit from batch consumer endpoint given out of the box.

What you can do is to create endpoints for chunked messages and process them inside workflow if you can speed up operations. So one solution would be for example to have batching component included before publisher class and send custom messages.